# Removing "There is no account with that username or email address." error message in "/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"

Tags: php, customization, hooks, login, wp-login-form

Would like to find out if there is any way I could customize the wp_login page to remove the "There is no account with that username or email address." validation (show below)

[image]

and any email/username entered are all redirected to this check email page instead?

[image]

I understand making change to wp-login.php is not advisable.

Seeking experts here for recommendation and advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if sending a confirmation link is possible then that first screen should be impossible, can you explain the problem that this would solve for you? Doing this would have negative security consequences as it would be possible to list unconfirmed users for exploitation

Comment: Hi Tom, my intention of removing this email check validation is to prevent user enumeration attacks.  Without this validation in place, there is no longer a "hint" made known to an attacker to guess or confirm if the email entered is a valid account to my WP portal.

Comment: Do you mean that if I disable the validation check, the confirmation link will be sent out regardless the email entered is a valid or a non-existing account in my portal? I think this can be customized on the PHP end to prevent that right?

Comment: I believe I misunderstood